# uniq : only when different by more than 1 character OR case

Tags: linux, sorting, uniq

I got a text file with LOTS of names.
I want  a list of all the strings(lines) that is either
1) Different in  CASE (i.e audi vs AuDI)
2) Different by more than 1 character ie (mygoo VS my-goo)
Any ideas ??

Comment: When do you consider two lines similar then? Only of they match exactly or have up to one character inserted? Can that character be a letter or only a symbol? What are you trying to do this for exactly, is it to eliminate accidental variations in manually inserted strings?

Comment: okey the test to be the same it would be something like this: foobar=foobar or audi=audi I want all the lines that are diffrent in CASE OR 1 Character like foobar!=fooBar or foobar!=foo-bar <-- these are the lines i want.

Answer (score 0):

you really mean *more than 1 character* difference? it would match all words, wouldn't?

if you mean *at most X difference(s)*, you can use [agrep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agrep) fuzzy search.

e.g. for following /tmp/list

```
bar
foobar
fooBar
foo-bar
foo--bar
spam
toolbar
```

command

```
$ agrep -1 foobar /tmp/list
```

will find:

```
foobar
fooBar
foo-bar
```

(it includes the original pattern, which you can filter out, e.g. appending `| grep -v '^foobar$'`)

#### UPDATE

this is a hint about a tool, which you can use, it might not be exactly what you wanted. please look at `-i` agrep option as well